# Special character issue in Excel for CSV file, Sheetjs prepend BOM for utf8 CSV files

Tags: node.js, excel, amazon-s3, xlsx, sheetjs

I am using https://www.npmjs.com/package/xlsx library to create CSV.

This is the final code to write CSV code

```
let workbook: WorkBook = this.workBookCreator.getWorkbook(workBookName);

return this.xlsxModule.write(workbook, {
     bookType: format,
     type: "buffer"
});
```

And that will be uploaded to `S3` bucket.

To download file

```
window.location.href = fileLocation;
```

Where `fileLocation` is the S3 pre-signed URL with a GET request.

When the downloaded file opens in Microsoft Excel, Special characters are messed up due to UTF-8 charset are not being recognized by EXCEL.

Can anyone please help me, how can I set charset UTF-8 while creating CSV to support all special characters to Excel?

**I have tried the below solutions so far:**

1. Tried to change the buffer type of XLSX
2. Added IconV & IconV-lite for buffer conversion
3. Changed the Content-type of the S3 bucket file.
4. Tried to change buffer type to string

I know we can prepend BOM to CSV file while writing. But couldn't find from where I can prepend.

Comment: What problems did you run into when you tried the various methods recommended in this forum for similar questions? Off the top of my head, two methods include writing a BOM to the file; **importing** into Excel, possibly using Power Query.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I have updated the Question with my attempts so far. Could you please guide me to the link for Power Query? Or can you please elaborate more?

Comment: PQ is available in Excel 2010+ (as a free MS add-in in 2010-2013, built-in in 2016+). When you import using PQ, there will be an option to set the **File Origin**. IIRC, 65001 is for UTF8.

Comment: That is I don't want to force users to do manual steps.

Comment: Then you will either have to set it up as a refreshable query, and convince your users to **import** and not **open** the file; or you will have to figure out how to add the `BOM` to the file when you  create it.  To do the latter, I suggest you do an internet search. `Sheetjs prepend bom for utf8 csv files` returned about 10,000 results on Google.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So, Finally, I found the solution (Tried too many google search)

I used [iconv-lite](https://www.npmjs.com/package/iconv-lite) npm package

**And here is code:**

```
const txt = '\uFEFF'+ iconV.decode(CSVString, 'utf8');
CSVString = iconV.encode(txt, 'utf8');
```

Hope, I can save someone's day!

Comment: The utf-8 bom is the important detail. As soon as sheetjs sees the bom, the encoding is read correctly.